# Fix double-encoded data

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have a field defined as `Question VARCHAR(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL`. Our application stored double-encoded data into this field. For example, `é` shows up as `Ã©` in phpMyAdmin, and `C383C2A9` when passed to `HEX`.

I've added a second field (`DoubleEncoded TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`), which identifies which records suffer from this problem.

I want to fix the remaining fields. Is there a way to do this using MySQL SQL? In other words, I need something to replace `decode_utf8` in the following:

```
UPDATE `MyTable`
   SET `Question` = decode_utf8(`Question`),
       `DoubleEncoded` = 0
 WHERE `DoubleEncoded` = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(`Question` USING latin1) USING binary) USING utf8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data appears to be correctly encoded in UTF-8.   phpMyAdmin is rendering the UTF-8 string using latin1 configuration.

Fix your phpMyAdmin and/or web server configuration, not your data.  You may have set the default configuration of your webserver to ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8, or phpMyAdmin may be setting this encoding.  It is possible to have headers specifying both encodings using different headers.  Different browsers resolve this differently, so you may get a different rendering if you use a different browser.

Comment: It's nice of you to think there was no bug in our application, but that's not the case. I realize that a UTF-8 `é` would look like what I posted on a latin1 terminal (which explains why the solution involves latin1), but I assure you, the data is double-encoded due to a bug in our application. phpMyAdmin is rendering correctly. In fact, I've never known it not to render properly, which is why the first thing I always ask when people have db encoding problem is "how does it look in phpMyAdmin?"

Comment: @ikegami - Then I come along and say that that is not adequate.  Only `SELECT HEX(col) ...` can check for sure on what is _stored_.  `é` is `E9` in cp1250, cp1256, cp1257, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5, latin7, macroman; `C3A9` for utf8/utf8mb4; and `C383C2A9` if "double-encoded".

Comment: @Rick James, Indeed, `HEX` would be better

Comment: phpMyAdmin sets appropriate headers so that it doesn't vary by browser. I updated the question to include output of `HEX`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go changing the text until you have verified that it was *stored* incorrectly, and not merely *read* incorrectly.  Use `HEX()` as mentioned in "Test the data" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 .

Moving down in that same link, you can see the likely causes of the flawed data.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not the proof; it was there specifically to avoid these non-applicable answers. I shall update my question to show the 4 bytes in hex when I'm next at a computer.

Comment: I updated the question to include the output of `HEX`. The cause (UTF-8 text over a latin1 connection) had already been fixed (by switching to a UTF-8 connection) before I posted the question.